# InStrRev function cannot takens into consideration the " " space whatever the [compare ] argument is

Tags: excel, vba

InStrRev has something wrong. In file name actually gives the position from the beginning and not as it should be.
CODE

```
path = Left(f1.path, Len(f1.path) - (InStrRev(f1.path, "\", -1, vbTextCompare) + 4))
```

Comment: Also this applied to the statement Name oldpathname As newpathname

Answer (score 1):

I saw someone asked a similar question about to get the position of "." and he said it should return 4.
I made many test in my code and I found the following:
The function InStrRev find the string from the end but return its position from the beginning.
The issue about space character still not solved for me

Comment: And that's what the documentation says... IMHO, it's a good idea to split such long statements, for example store the result of InStrRev in a intermediate variable and check it in the debugger when something fails. Also, don't think that something is wrong with a basic VBA function - you can safely assume that they do their job.

Comment: Not justified. I have on my HDD files name with space and zeros like "360_0000.jpg" and "AnyText Ru.jpg". I want to renumbering them. Al  work except such models. Name path $ oldFileName As path & newFileName     
and other methods also does not work such "For Each f1 In files   ......           f1.Name = path & newFileName" for others without space and 0000 it work properly. So !!! they did not do their work !!

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *not justified*. If your code doesn't work, you should really check your code and try to understand why it doesn't work. Stating that a VBA function does something wrong will not help you. VBA is used by millions of people since I don't know maybe 25 years - you can surely assume that the problem is on your side, not on theirs. If you don't understand something, feel free to ask here on SO (but do your research first).

Comment: So I created some of your mentioned files and executed a `name` command - no problems, everything works. I have the suspicion that you are somehow a victim of the fact that Windows creates a 2nd filename internally to fit the old 8.3 naming conventions. In that case, you might hit a case where you want to rename a file and that interferes with an already existing name. What is there error you get?

Comment: The point is: It works. If it doesn't work, it fails for a reason, and it throws a runtime error, and it is highly likely that the same command would fail also on OS-level (I would think that the `name` command is just a small wrapper). So what is the error you get?

Comment: @FunThomas I meant, you cannot justify them (Microsoft vba team).In their help page they mentioned to wildcards '*' and '?' and space ' ' is included as you told me. OK agreed. But can you tell me why one of the following lines work where the other not ? I am programmer (~33 years) for many Languages. and mainly Mech Eng. so I can understand you fast. (.JPG & .jpg work both)                           **Name "D:\Test\660_000010.JPG" As "D:\Test\760_0009.JPG"**  work                                           **Name "D:\Test\660_000010.JPG" As "D:\Test\660_0009.JPG"**  doesn't work**

Comment: @FunThomas. I mean that if the newFileName has the same first character of the oldFileName... the "Name" doesn't work.. I think there is lot of exception, sometimes it work I don't know why. I have 360_ series files some renamed correctly some not even the new name is 360_....something

Comment: You still don't tell what error you get. You can perfectly rename a file with the same prefix, also blanks are not an issue. What *might* be an issue is the filename that is generated in the background to match the old file name syntax. Which is an OS-issue, not an issue of the VBA command

Comment: Why I did not tell you the error? when I run the procedure, some files are renamed successfully where the others remain unchanged

Comment: If a file is not renamed, the `name` command must have issued an error. Do you have, by any chance, an `On Error Resume Next` command somewhere in your code? If yes, throw it away (as far as you can...)

Comment: Ahhh, yes I have it in the first of the code. I use it to warning the user in Excel that the path does not exist. So how to disable it after this checking? I mean to cancel On error resume next? Thanks man :)

Comment: I used MsgBox err.description and I got after "Name" As usage                                    "Application-defined or object-defined error"          My error maybe start from here                                                        Set files = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") .GetFolder(baseFolderName).files ' I resume the variables to reduce lines for you    All are type of "Object" and not "Collection" to get the folder and its Contents of files. but note that it work for hundred of other files.

Comment: Sorry @FunThomas after I err.clear it from the beginning, there is no additional error generated in err.description I have something strange. before "Name" usage Err.Number <> 0 not true, so no error. after it exactly it give an error of "File already exist" and my code at that moment    Name path & fileName As path & newFileName  which equivalent in variables values to  ---- >    Name "D:\test\360_0000.jpg" As "D:\test\360_0001.jpg"

Comment: @FunThomas and nothing renamed, unless I change the newFileName value:  the 360_ (before the '_' ) to another value like 460_ or 370_ the file will be renamed

Comment: Hi, I think you should open a new question, our discussion has nothing to do with the `InstrRev`-question above. Post all relevant code and ask why the rename is not working. In that way, someone else with a similar question can find it in the future